# mobile app token for login user authentication

Tags: authentication, oauth, token, mobile-application

I'm sure thousands have already asked it, and I searched it for at least 2 weeks, but couldn't find a simple answer.

I have a mobile app where I have a login system so the process is very simple:

1. user logs in with email, password
2. server checks data and returns OK and a user token
3. now each request of the user will be with the token attached
4. server gets a request with token, checks if it is valid for a user and continues.

Now my problem is how do I store the token:

1. I want to have several tokens for same user (logs from iphone, ipad...)
2. until when this tokens exist? when do I delete them?

Any ideas on what are the best practices?

Answer (score 0):

OH ，I'm also looking for it, and I just know the token could be stored with Redis/Memcache on Server Side.